# Convert this 4x4 matrix to identity using row operations only

Tags: matrices

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1&1\\1&1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}

Please tell me the steps how to do it?
I have tried

R4 - > R4+R3
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

R3 - > R2+R3

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&-1\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

R1 -> R1 + R2

\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2&0\\1&1&1&-1\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

now after doing R2 -> R2+R4 THEN  R2 -> R2-R3 THEN R1 -> R1 - 2R3, I got

\begin{bmatrix}2&2&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I'm stuck here
Thank you!

Comment: Well, it is definitely possible to reduce the matrix to its reduced row echelon form using row operations. Is the RREF of this matrix equal to the identity? That's for you to decide.

Comment: What does the original matrix do to the c olumn vector $$\left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
1  \\ 
-1  \\  0 \\ 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$  ?

Comment: After your last step, bring $R_1$ to the bottom of the matrix, and then add to it $(-2) \times R_1$, now you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it is possible to obtain the identity matrix $I_4$ starting from $A$ and performing row operations. Therefore, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PA=I_4$. This proves that $\det(PA)=1$, and then $\det(P)\det(A)=1$, which implies that $A$ is invertible.

However, if we denote $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$, and $R_4$ as the rows of $A$, it can be observed that
$$
-R_1+R_2+R_3+R_4=0
$$
so that $A$ is not invertible ; $\det(A)=0$.

Therefore, it is impossible to obtain $I_4$ starting from $A$ and performing row operations.

Have a great day!